# C# Regular Expression matching valid HTML attribute value

Tags: c#, regex, html-parsing, w3c-validation

### Does anyone have this Regular Expression?

```
 public static class HtmlAttributeValidator{

     const bool REGEX_OPTIONS = RegexOptions.WhatGoesHere;

     const string VALID_ATTRIBUTE_REGEX = @"What goes here?";

     public static bool IsValidHtmlAttributeValue(string attributeValue){
           return Regex.Match(attributeValue ?? string.Empty, 
                              VALID_ATTRIBUTE_REGEX, 
                              REGEX_OPTIONS);
     }

 }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You will not find such a regular expression, because many attribute values can take *any* valid textual value, hence the values are *not* regular and can't be matched by a regular expression.

See [this](http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/index/attributes.html) list of HTML attributes and the values they can take. In particular note the ones that take [CDATA](http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/types.html#type-cdata) values:

> CDATA is a sequence of characters from the document character set and may include character entities.

Comment: Can an html attribute value ever contain a double quote or a tag?  It seems like this would be a constraint.  I am not trying to match the regex of the tag individually, but the base regex which all attributes must meet.

Comment: @smartcaveman - if you delimit the value with single quotes, you can use double quotes in it. If you don't you need to escape the quotes using `&quote;`. As for `<` - it is recommended to always escape it as `&lt;`.